# Check-and-set in Couchbase Java SDK 2.x?

Tags: java, couchbase, optimistic-locking

In older version of Couchbase Java SDK there were several [**check-and-set (CAS) methods**](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/#couchbase-sdk-java-update-cas) for implementing **optimistic locking**. But what is corresponding API in a newer version of SDK (>= 2.0)?

Initial code:

```
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get("myKey");
Long casValue = doc.cas();
// some method to set new value for "myKey" only if CAS value 
//   has not been changed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already saw, the CAS value is embedded in the document. Most methods in the API will take that into account if the CAS is not 0, for example `replace(Document)` will throw a `CASMismatchException` if the given document has a different CAS value than what is on the server.

Comment: This answers my question and I've already accepted it, but maybe you also know how to create new document with specific CAS (instead of in-place modification of existing document)?

Comment: When you create a document eg. using `JsonDocument.create` there is an overload that allows you to set the cas

Comment: @SimonBaslé I am never able to catch the CASMismatchException. When there are two threads that are trying to modify a document concurrently (the cas value will be the same for both the documents when they read the document) and one thread modifies the document and replaces it in the server which in turn changes the cas value. After this when the second thread, which also modifies the document, tries to replace, the cas value just gets overriden instead of throwing CASMismatchException. Is there a way to catch this exception?

Comment: @SimonBaslé There is an enum `ResponseStatus` which has the enum variable `EXISTS` which should be set when the request expected the document to not exist, but it existed already. Only when this condition is met, `CASMismatchException` is thrown for the `bucket.replace()` right?